# What am I doing wrong with setting up i18next in React? Getting a "i18next::translator: missingKey" error

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, i18next

In my `src` folder, I made a folder called `i18n`, and it contains these three files

```
en.json
es.json
pl.json
```

This is what they look like:

```
{
  "selectAction": "Select Action",
  "workflow": "Workflow",
  "details": "Details"
}
```

In `src` folder, I also added this file called `i18n.js`

```
import i18n from 'i18next'
import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector"
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next'
// import Backend from "i18next-xhr-backend";
// import XHR from 'i18next-xhr-backend'
import languageEn from './i18n/en.json'
import languageEs from './i18n/es.json'
import languagePl from './i18n/pl.json'

i18n
  // .use(Backend)
  // .use(XHR)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    resources: {
      en: languageEn,
      es: languageEs,
      pl: languagePl
    },
    lng: "es",
    fallbackLng: "en",
    debug: true,
    keySeparator: ".",
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    }
  });

console.log(i18n.languages)

export default i18n;
```

My index.js file in the src root looks like this:

```
// import statements are omitted, but I am importing I18NextProvider and i18n
ReactDOM.render(
  <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
    <App />
  </I18nextProvider>
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Lastly, somewhere in my App I have this:

```
// Other imports omitted
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

const DetailsPlaceholder = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  return (
     <h4 className="zero-state-section-text">{t('selectAction')}</h4>
  );
};

export default DetailsPlaceholder;
```

When I try to load the page, I see the key 'selectAction' as the text (instead of the real text), and this error gets logged:

```
i18next::translator: missingKey es translation selectAction selectAction
```

Comment: do you have selectAction in 'es.json' file  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All resource files should store strings under `translation` key (like in [quick start for `react-i18next`](https://react.i18next.com/guides/quick-start#configure-i-18-next)):

```json
{
  "translation": {
    "selectAction": "Select Action",
    "workflow": "Workflow",
    "details": "Details"
  }
}
```

Here is a repository with a reproduced error and fixed configuration:
https://github.com/terales/reproduce-react-i18next-missingkey-error